# Could not build wheels for record3d, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, cmake, pip, python-wheel, lidar

Working on streaming LiDAR data from my phone to my PC and i run into this error when i try to run "pip install record3d" I get an error. I'm relatively inexperienced with these kinds of things, so please excuse me if I didn't upload all the information you need to help me. I'll gladly reply with more info if you ask for it!

Windows 10 64x
Running on VSCode

I tried "pip install record3d" and was expecting it to install, however I got:

```
C:\Users\aboud>pip install record3d
Collecting record3d
  Using cached record3d-1.3.1-2.tar.gz (548 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\aboud\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from record3d) (1.26.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: record3d
  Building wheel for record3d (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [63 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      C:\Users\aboud\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3wai_i0f\record3d_39f6a6e1cbff41099e3ee8d64013c385\setup.py:29: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
        cmake_version = LooseVersion(re.search(r'version\s*([\d.]+)', out.decode()).group(1))
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
        Generator
     
          NMake Makefiles
     
        does not support platform specification, but platform
     
          x64
     
        was specified.
     
     
      CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```